# Mongoose subdocument array update

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-populate, mern, subdocument

please help me with a mongoose code to push a string in an array of a particular sub-document after finding it.

1. How to find and retrieve a sub-document
2. Update an array in it
3. Save it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here members is subdocument in club
take a look at this. this will definetly solve the problem

```
router.post("/update", verify, async (req, res) => {
      Club.findOneAndUpdate(
        {
          _id: req.club._id,
          "Members.name": req.club.Mem_Name,
        },
        {
          $set: {
            "Members.$.email": req.body.email,
            "Members.$.phonenumber": req.body.phonenumber,
            "Members.$.graduationyear": req.body.graduationyear,
            "Members.$.reg": req.body.reg,
          },
        },
        { multi: true },
        (err, doc) => {
          if (err) console.log(err);
          else res.json(doc);
        }
      );
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

> At first you retrieve the document
>   then you can push like(doc.push(data))
>   then doc.save()